# Swift - MultipeerConnectivity Type does not conform to protocol

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, multipeer-connectivity

I am trying out [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/chat-app-swift-tutorial/) and having some problem with the code:

```
class MPCManager: NSObject, MCSessionDelegate, MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate, MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate {
```

I got an error:

> Type 'MPCManager' does not comform to protocol 'MCSessionDelegate'
>
> Type 'MPCManager' does not comform to protocol 'MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate'
>
> Type 'MPCManager' does not comform to protocol 'MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate'

But I download the sample file it did not get the same error. Which part had I missed out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement all the required delegate methods of `MCSessionDelegate` and `MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate` and `MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate`, if you want to conform to these protocols.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add all the required delegate methods of that protocol.

I have added all the required method into below code:

```
import Foundation
import MultipeerConnectivity


class MPCManager: NSObject, MCSessionDelegate, MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate, MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate {

    //Type 'MPCManager' does not comform to protocol 'MCSessionDelegate'
    // Remote peer changed state
    func session(session: MCSession!, peer peerID: MCPeerID!, didChangeState state: MCSessionState){

    }

    // Received data from remote peer
    func session(session: MCSession!, didReceiveData data: NSData!, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID!){

    }

    // Received a byte stream from remote peer
    func session(session: MCSession!, didReceiveStream stream: NSInputStream!, withName streamName: String!, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID!){

    }

    // Start receiving a resource from remote peer
    func session(session: MCSession!, didStartReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String!, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID!, withProgress progress: NSProgress!){

    }

    // Finished receiving a resource from remote peer and saved the content in a temporary location - the app is responsible for moving the file to a permanent location within its sandbox
    func session(session: MCSession!, didFinishReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String!, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID!, atURL localURL: NSURL!, withError error: NSError!){

    }


    //Type 'MPCManager' does not comform to protocol 'MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate'

    // Found a nearby advertising peer
    func browser(browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser!, foundPeer peerID: MCPeerID!, withDiscoveryInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]!){

    }

    // A nearby peer has stopped advertising
    func browser(browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser!, lostPeer peerID: MCPeerID!){

    }

    //Type 'MPCManager' does not comform to protocol 'MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate'
    // Incoming invitation request.  Call the invitationHandler block with YES and a valid session to connect the inviting peer to the session.
    func advertiser(advertiser: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser!, didReceiveInvitationFromPeer peerID: MCPeerID!, withContext context: NSData!, invitationHandler: ((Bool, MCSession!) -> Void)!){

    }

}
```

If you want to check what are the required methods for specific delegate then just command + click on that delegate and you will find all the methods related with that delegate suppose if you command + click on `MCSessionDelegate` then you will see something like this:

```
// Delegate methods for MCSession
protocol MCSessionDelegate : NSObjectProtocol {

    // Remote peer changed state
    func session(session: MCSession!, peer peerID: MCPeerID!, didChangeState state: MCSessionState)

    // Received data from remote peer
    func session(session: MCSession!, didReceiveData data: NSData!, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID!)

    // Received a byte stream from remote peer
    func session(session: MCSession!, didReceiveStream stream: NSInputStream!, withName streamName: String!, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID!)

    // Start receiving a resource from remote peer
    func session(session: MCSession!, didStartReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String!, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID!, withProgress progress: NSProgress!)

    // Finished receiving a resource from remote peer and saved the content in a temporary location - the app is responsible for moving the file to a permanent location within its sandbox
    func session(session: MCSession!, didFinishReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String!, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID!, atURL localURL: NSURL!, withError error: NSError!)

    // Made first contact with peer and have identity information about the remote peer (certificate may be nil)
    optional func session(session: MCSession!, didReceiveCertificate certificate: [AnyObject]!, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID!, certificateHandler: ((Bool) -> Void)!)
}
```

Where only last method is optional so if you do not add it your delegate works fine but you have to add all above 5 methods into your class to conform the protocol.

Hope It will help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the protocols of the delegates. You can find it out when typing functions in xcode.

Comment: I'd like to add that if you see the reported errors (non conforming) that if you click on the red circle, you can look in the left panel at the errors and expand the error.  Xcode will then indicate which routine has the issue or which routine is missing.  In addition, you can begin typing the function name in the code section, and the declaration will appear.